Android Studio Flutter plugin errors after enabling code completion
I use Android Studio and Flutter. Flutter Doctor does not show any problems. The codes also work. But when I activate Flutter's code completion option and restart Android Studio, I encounter these 4 errors:
Exception in IDEA CORE plugin:
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: setPath was not yet called [Plugin: com.intellij]

Exception in Gradle plugin:
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: @NotNull method org/jetbrains/plugins/gradle/settings/GradleSettings.getInstance must not return null [Plugin: com.intellij.gradle]

Exception in plugin Android Apk Support:
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: Cannot invoke "com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.settings.AbstractExternalSystemSettings.getLinkedProjectsSettings()" because "settings" is null [Plugin: com.android.tools.apk]

Exception in Flutter plugin:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: GradleSyncState service is not registered

Android Studio==2024.2.1 Patch 2
Flutter==3.24.3
Dart==3.5.3
plugins:
Flutter==82.0.3
Dart==242.22855.32






